# How to use a custom user provider with Symfony 3 authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication

I've been trying for days to get Symfony 3 authentication working with a custom "user provider".   I've followed this tutorial in the Symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html which shows the example of getting user data from a webservice.

I've done everything according to that page (and other pages in Symfo docs), and tried many variation of the details.  The Symfony authentication never calls my WebserviceUserProvider.  My WebserviceUserProvider implements `loadUserByUsername($username)` as required, but an echo statement in that method never executes.

Here are files created or changed.   `WebserviceUser`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;
/*
 * src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUser.php
 */
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

class WebserviceUser implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable
{
    private $id = 0;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;
    private $isActive;
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // DEGUBBING
        echo "creating new WebserviceUser";
    }


    // ----------------- getters

    public function getId()         { return $this->id;    }
    public function getEmail()      { return $this->email;    }
    public function isActive()      { return $this->isActive;    }
    // next four are required by the interface
    public function getRoles()      { return $this->roles;    }
    public function getPassword()   { return $this->password;    }
    public function getSalt()       { return null;    }
    public function getUsername()   { return $this->username;    }


    // ------------------------------ setters

    public function setId(int $i)           { $this->id = $i;    }
    public function setEmail(string $s)     { $this->email = $s;    }
    public function setIsActive(bool $b)    { $this->isActive = $b; }
    public function setRoles(array $a)      { $this->roles = $a;    }
    public function setPassword(string $s)  { $this->password = $s;    }
    public function setSalt(string $s)      { $this->salt = $s; }
    public function setUsername(string $s)  { $this->username = $s;    }


    // ----------------------------- misc.

    // required by interface
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        // copied exactly from tuto
        // ...

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        // copied exactly from tuto
        // ...

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // copied exactly from tuto
        // ...

}
```

The `WebserviceUserProvider`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security\User;
/*
 * src/AppBundle/Security/User/WebserviceUserProvider.php
 */
use AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // Symfo docs sample: "make a call to your webservice here
        // $userData = ... 
        // "

        echo "This is WebserviceUserProvider::loadUserByUsername()";

        $user =  new WebserviceUser();
        $user->setUsername('testname');
        $user->setPassword('testpass');
        $user->setEmail('test@none.com');
        $user->setIsActive(true);
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if(!$user instanceof WebserviceUser){
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                'Class is ' . get_class($user) . ', must be WebserviceUser');
        }
        return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return WebserviceUser::class === $class;
    }
}
```

My `security.yml`:

```
# app/config/security.yml
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
security:

    encoders:
        # BCrypt encoder
        ### Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User4:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm:            bcrypt
            cost:                 13
        AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUser:
            algorithm:            bcrypt
            cost:                 13
        AppBundle\Entity\UserRegister:
            algorithm:            bcrypt
            cost:                 13

    providers:
        #in_memory:
        #    memory: ~

        webservice:
            id: AppBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider

    //hide_user_not_found: false

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler,
        # adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            #http_basic: ~

            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

    access_control:
        # Order matters in this list. Each path controls all under it and later
        # more specific does not overrule - so go from more specific to less.
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/survey, roles: ROLE_ORG_USER }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

// ...
```

The `access_control` part, and the form page all work as expected.  A login attempt always gets the message `Invalid credentials` (as it should).  Looking at the output of `$authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError()` in the controller gets a stack trace that does not contain any reference to "webservice".

I've tried many different tweaks of all the above, looked up many Q&A on SO and many howtos, without finding anything helpful.  The above is incomplete as you can tell, but all I need is to get Symfony to use the provider and then I can handle the rest.

It's obviously working for others out there but I can't tell what they're doing differently.  What am I missing?

Edit: The stack trace is like this:

```
error: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException: The presented password is invalid. in /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:67 Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php(144): session_start()
#1 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php(282): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
#2 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php(259): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->getBag('attributes')
#3 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php(87): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->getAttributeBag()
#4 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php(83): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->get('_security_main')
#5 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall.php(69): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#6 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/EventListener/FirewallListener.php(48): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#7 [internal function]: Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher))
#8 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php(104): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher))
#9 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#10 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212): call_user_func(Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#11 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#12 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php(146): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#13 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(129): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#14 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#15 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php(171): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#16 /srv/www/site1/web/app_dev.php(28): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#17 /srv/www/site1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebServerBundle/Resources/router.php(42): require('/srv/www/site1...')
#18 {main}
```

Update:
The last (first-listed) item in the trace looked the most likely, that is `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php`.  And `DaoAuthenticationProvider::checkAuthentication()` (where l. 67 is) takes arguments `UserInterface $user` and `UsernamePasswordToken $token`, so I put `dump($user);` and `dump($token);` just before the `if ... throw`, and finally understood what's been happening.

As Grzegorz Gajda's reply said, the Symfony code tries each provider and goes for another one if the username doesn't match - but the thing that threw me off was that it somehow *suppresses the echo statement* if there's no match!  So it seemed as if it wasn't hitting the service at all.  But as soon as I put the dump statements in, the echos appeared and confirmed it was hitting the provider.

And once I hardcoded some known-good values, it authenticated and I was logged in.  This proves it does work, albeit misleadingly, and now I just need to hook up the actual request to the data source and it will all be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Symfony's `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\ChainUserProvider` takes all defined providers (yours and default ones) and iterate them until find at least one user matching username ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/ChainUserProvider.php)).

#### Symfony's Security component

Perhaps in your DB you have user with username `testname` and your provider is not fired. As you can see in [line 62](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/ChainUserProvider.php#L62) default `ChainUserProvider` throws an exception with message `There is no user with name "%s".`, not `Invalid credentials`.

Ok, but how about `AuthenticationException::getMessageKey()`? It is used to display translated message so we can rely on exception message. It's time to investigate securities' exception. `UsernameNotFoundException` contains message ['Username could not be found.'](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6db73d3f4e47fad0be4973b83fb3402bd2321b35/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/UsernameNotFoundException.php#L29), `BadCredentialsException` contains ['Invalid credentials.'](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6db73d3f4e47fad0be4973b83fb3402bd2321b35/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/BadCredentialsException.php#L27). Our provider should return `UsernameNotFoundException` when any provider has not user with username `testname`.

#### Solution

You can select yours one and only one provider for whole provider ([documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#configure-security-to-load-from-your-entity)) or even create your own chain provider and use its.

Comment: The "Invalid credentials" is due to the twig line: `{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}` which outputs that phrase in place of the actual trace.  The real message has "BadCredentialsException".  The "testname" is bogus and not expected to work - I'm just trying to understand why the echo statement never executes.  The lack of it says to me that the provider is never called.  As you can see the webservice is the only provider listed.

Comment: Try to find your stack trace during authentication and find what Guard checks your password and make `dump()` there with list of providers.